# Number of ways to divide $n$-distinct things into $m$ $r$-sized groups

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How do you divide $n$ distinct things into $m$ $r$-sized groups?

The way I am approaching is doing $$\binom{n}{r} \binom{n-r}{r} \binom{n-2r}{r} .... \binom{n-ir}{r}$$ till $n-ir=r$, which is very tedious.

The question I was solving asked the number of ways of dividing 200 people into 100 pairs.

Additionally, how should I approach if the n object are similar?

Answer (score 1):

Simply note that $$\begin{eqnarray}\binom nr \binom{n-r}{r}\binom{n-2r}{r}\dots\binom{n-ir}{r}  &=& \frac{n!}{r!\cdot(n-r)!}\cdot\frac{(n-r)!}{r!\cdot (n-2r)!}\dots\frac{(n-(m-1)r)!}{r!\cdot(n-mr)!}\\
&=& \frac{n!}{(r!)^{m}}\end {eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 0):

For the question of dividing $200$ people into $100$ pairs,
your "tedious" formula simplifies to $\dfrac{200!}{2^{100}}$

If the objects are similar, eg $200$ balls to be divided into pairs, there'd just be $100$ indistinguishable pairs, wouldn't there ?

**NOTE**

You should familiarize yourself with the multinomial coefficient.
For the more general problem of dividing $n$ people into $m\;\; r$-sized groups, with $mr = n$, the multinomial coefficient would be

$\dbinom{n}{r,r,r,....} = \dfrac{n!}{(r!)^m}$

Comment: Can you show how you simplified it?

Comment: Take a smaller example of $8$ people.  
$\binom82\binom62\binom42\binom22 = \frac{8\cdot7}2\frac{6\cdot5}2\frac{4\cdot3}2\frac{2\cdot1}2 = \frac{8!}{2^4}$